# need to split value after pipe '|'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

This is my output

```
MUR,USD,EUR|SEM
```

I want in this way

```
1) MUR,USD,EUR
2) SEM
```

I am using SQL Server.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: search for delimited splitter. There are lots of similar thread around

Comment: @gowdhaman i have tried split function

Comment: that should work. Please post what you have tried

Comment: DECLARE strIssuerIds VARCHAR (250)

SELECT @strIssuerIds =  ParaValue
FROM dbo.mstParameters WHERE ParaCode = 'FAW_local_Currencies_exchange_001' 


SELECT Item FROM dbo.fnSplitItems( strIssuerIds, ',')

Comment: you need to split on the `PIPE` but in your code `dbo.fnSplitItems( strIssuerIds, ',') ` you split by `comma`

Answer (score 1):

Try this (comments in code):

```
declare @tbl table(col varchar(100));
insert into @tbl values ('MUR,USD,EUR|SEM');

--select everything before the pipe
select SUBSTRING(col, 1, CHARINDEX('|', col) - 1)
from @tbl
union all
--union all with everything after the pipe
select SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('|', col) + 1, LEN(col))
from @tbl

--alternative
select SUBSTRING(col, 1, CHARINDEX('|', col) - 1) BeforePipe,
       SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('|', col) + 1, LEN(col)) AfterPipe
from @tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

**Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( *emphasized text*
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

**Output**

SELECT * FROM DBO.fnSplitString('Querying|SQL Server','|')

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function like this and used this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SPLITTEXT(
          @delimited NVARCHAR(MAX),
          @delimiter NVARCHAR(100)
        ) RETURNS @t TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), val NVARCHAR(MAX))
        AS
        BEGIN
          DECLARE @xml XML
          SET @xml = N'<t>' + REPLACE(@delimited,@delimiter,'</t><t>') + '</t>'

          INSERT INTO @t(val)
          SELECT  r.value('.','varchar(MAX)') as item
          FROM  @xml.nodes('|') as records(r)
          RETURN
        END
```

and when you use this function like

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SPLITTEXT] ('MUR,USD,EUR|SEM.', ' ')
```

output is

```
MUR,USD,EUR
SEM
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2016 or more you can do it:

```
select T1.Value from STRING_SPLIT( 'MUR,USD,EUR|SEM' , '|' ) as T1
```

Detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)